# Sequelize & Typescript: many to many self association and getter method

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, sequelize.js

I am pretty new to Sequelize and I am trying to use it in a project written through Typescript in order to develop a GraphQL API server. I am aware that there is `sequelize/typescript` that should ensure integration between Sequelize and TS but I would prefer to use the official `sequelize` package and integrate it with TS by myself.
I have this `Part` model:

```
  public id!: number;
  public name!: string;
  public thumb?: string;
}

Part.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    thumb: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'part',
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'parts',
    timestamps: false,
  }
);

Part.belongsToMany(Part, {
  through: { model: MacroProductModel },
  as: 'children',
  foreignKey: 'parentPartNo',
  otherKey: 'childPartNo',
});

export type PartModelStatic = typeof Model & {
  new (values?: Record<string, unknown>, options?: BuildOptions): Part;
};

export default Part as PartModelStatic;
```

As you can see, I have defined a self many-to-many association that I have defined according to Sequelize [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html#self-references).
What I would like to do is to use the getter method related to `Part` model to retrieve `children` from a `Part` model instance.
I have written a `resolver` for `Part` type where I created a custom `resolver` in order to retrieve each `child` for a `Part` instance, according to the data inserted in the `macro_products` table (the one used in the `belongsToMany` call in `Part` model class).

```
const resolvers: Resolvers = {
  Part: {
    subparts: async (parent, _, { models }) => {
      const parentPart = await models.Part.findByPk(parent.id, { include: { model: models.Part, as: 'children' } });
      if (parentPart) {
        return parentPart.getChildren();
      }
      return [];
    },
  },
};
```

I receive an error from Typescript because `Property 'getChildren' does not exist on type 'Part'`. The only way I was able to find to avoid this error is declaring a property `getChildren` in `Part` class (above the line `public thumb?: string;`). After have done this, everything works like expected and I am able to retrieve the desired information.

Could maybe someone please help me in understanding how to make this flow work without adding that line in the model class declaration?

Thanks a lot!